# Toric surfaces among rational surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry, birational-geometry

I'm learning about rational surfaces. Precisely, I've just read that all minimal rational projective, smooth surfaces are $\mathbb{P}^2$ and the Hirzebruch surfaces $\mathbb{F}_n$, for $n=0,2,3,\ldots$ Here minimal (at least in the algebraic category) means that inside the surface there are no $\mathbb{P}^1$'s with self-intersection equal to $-1$. It is known that every surface dominates (in the sense of birational geometry) a minimal surface and that such minimal model can be obtained contracting these $(-1)$-curves. On the other hand, starting from a given surface, $(-1)$-curves can be produced using the process of blowing-up. It seems to me that blowing-up and contraction are mutual inverse operations.

It turns out that all the above surfaces ($\mathbb{P}^2$ and the $\mathbb{F}_n$) are toric surfaces and I've read that in order to obtain the toric surface $\widetilde{X}$ which is the blow-up of a toric surface $X$ you must include in the fan (a combinatorial object) some rays.

My question is: does it show that every rational (smooth, projective) surface is toric?

If not, it comes the second question: how to distinguish the toric surfaces among the rational ones?

Thanks.

Comment: All toric surfaces are rational.

Comment: Certainly. My question is about the converse statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simples example of a non-toric surface is the blowup of three collinear points on a plane. To see that it is not toric, note that it has a unique $(-2)$-curve (the strict transform of the line through the blowup centers), which intersects exactly three $(-1)$-curves. So, if there is a torus action on this surface, it should preserve this $(-2)$-curve, and fix the three points on it. Hence, the whole $(-2)$-curve should consist of torus fixed points. But a toric surface has only isolated fixed points.

Comment: Thanks. It confirms my suspection. The failure of your surface to be a toric one comes from a special arrangement of the blown-up points. Do you know of arrangements that result a toric surface?

Comment: @amateur : it's not only the arrangement, for example if I remember well blowing up 8 points on $\Bbb P^2$ is never toric, independently of the chosen points.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Can you please give me a reference?

Comment: @amateur : in fact, even the blow-up at $4$ points is not toric. Indeed, each $(-1)$ curves is fixed by the torus action, so they should be contracted to $4$ different fixed points but there are only 3 fixed points for a torus action on $\Bbb P^2$.

Comment: @amateur: If you fix the torus action from the very beginning, then to keep the surface toric (for this action) you need to blowup only toric fixed points.

Comment: Why does the torus action have to fix the three points on the $(-2)$-curve, why can't it permute the points?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Because the torus is connected.